# How to start ssh-agent permanently with python?

Tags: python, linux, bsd, ssh-agent

I am looking for the equivalent of `eval $(ssh-agent)` for python, that will start ssh-agent and will stay running after the script finish to run.

I didn't find anything useful with Google.

Comment: Should ssh-agent be run as a system service rather than via python?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with python to answer directly. What you want in other languages would be called a "detached process". Search for that in python and see what turns up

Comment: The goal is to automate the start of ssh-agent on new machines for test automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use that https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh-agent-setup/0.2.0, but it was not working for me. Looking at the code on https://github.com/haarcuba/ssh-agent-setup I have found out that is was pretty easy to fix. I did fork and do a pull request https://github.com/haarcuba/ssh-agent-setup/pull/2.

For those who are interested in using ssh-agent-setup python module, you can follow the instruction https://github.com/haarcuba/ssh-agent-setup#ssh-agent-setup.

If you get:

```
ssh_agent_setup.setup()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ssh_agent_setup/__init__.py", line 34, in setup
    _setupAgent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ssh_agent_setup/__init__.py", line 18, in _setupAgent
    raise Exception( 'Could not parse ssh-agent output. It was: {}'.format( process.stdout ) )
Exception: Could not parse ssh-agent output. It was: setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-thoTQTiOTR0y/agent.47524;
setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 47797;
echo Agent pid 47797;
```

The fix is https://github.com/haarcuba/ssh-agent-setup/pull/2/commits/d262228d379a4c58d357c7d5f83a579ca760e054#diff-39dd5525d88610b0c21a9bec4d2534b0

If anyone wants to implement a something similar the code is pretty easy to understand https://github.com/haarcuba/ssh-agent-setup/blob/master/ssh_agent_setup/__init__.py.

Reading the code, I now understand how ssh-agent can be started in python.